# run macro after print button

Tags: excel, vba

We are looking for a macro that after a user hits the print button will delete an entire row if Column I has value of zero.  Its deleting everything.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8baK2.jpg

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

   Sub DeleteRows()
   Dim c As Range
   Dim SrchRng

   Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Do
       Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me.

- Get rid of "Sub DeleteRows()" - Not sure why that was in your function
- Set SrchRng so that it only searches column I
- Remove the quotes from SrchRng.Find("0")

Here it is with the changes:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng
Set SrchRng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("I:I")) 'Just Search Column I
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(0, LookIn:=xlValues)                'Remove Quotes on this line
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Also, this should do the trick if you just want to use a For Loop

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim x
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For x = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(x, 9).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(x, 9).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like this is deleting everything where column I has nothing inside it. In this case I need the first 7 rows to never be deleted. http://i.imgur.com/7pqIBdi.jpg 

- Also the its not running the macro on 'print'